# Slideshow em diretório

Tags: php, diretório

O projeto é um **slideshow**, o mesmo deve percorrer um diretório específico onde se encontra um arquivo de imagem `jpg`, este arquivo terá o nome de `TEMP_IMAGE1.jpg`, e ao ser aberto será apresentado para o usuário no navegador. A cada iteração do *loop* para carregar a próxima imagem,
o nome do arquivo deve ser incrementado para `+1` *(no caso: na segunda iteração o nome será `TEMP_IMAGE2.jpg`.. e assim por diante...).*

> Qual a melhor maneira para se escrever o algoritmo em PHP ?

- Deve conter uma variável de controle para o intervalo entre a transição de uma imagem para outra.
- Se caso o arquivo de imagem `TEMP_IMAGEX.jpg` não existir ou falhar durante sua abertura, a iteração seguinte deve continuar tentando ler o mesmo arquivo.
- Um botão de controle, **Stop/Start** *(para pausar, e continuar o Slideshow)*

Sou desenvolvedor de outra linguagem, não possuo conhecimento avançado em **php** , um projeto como este requer domínio sob a linguagem, não tenho interesse em códigos prontos, quero *"orientações"* de algum *"expert"* para que eu possa me posicionar corretamente em meus estudos.

Comment: Como tu mesma disseste é muito avançado, talvez não tão avançado, mas exige raciocínio lógico para definir a aplicação, e tempo, algo que muita gente daqui não tem sempre a disposição, é muito pouco provável que consigas ajuda com um script completo, feito da base, sendo que tu não tens nenhuma parte dele já feita. Boa Sorte.

Comment: Como disse acima, necessito apenas de orientações para me posicionar nos estudos, qual função usar entre outras coisas.. a lógica já está feita, tenho essa aplicação rodando em c++, só preciso rescrever em php.

Comment: Adicionar o código em `C++` já feito, já seria qualquer coisa, mas ainda assim as probabilidades de conseguires ajuda para reescrever, a aplicação continuam ser poucas, dependendo do número de linhas, complexidade. De qualquer das formas, publica-o a ver se alguém atende a chamada.

Comment: Até onde sei, não é possível um slideshow em PHP e este seria usado somente para percorrer o diretório e extrair uma array com as imagens -isto aqui é tipo fácil, tem vários exemplos pela web. Depois disso seria CSS, JavaScript ou jQuery... também, muito exemplo por aí (ver exemplo de [slideshow com CSS puro](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/pure-css3-cycling-slideshow/)). `A melhor maneira` é aquela que atende seus requisitos específicos, não existe fórmula pronta.